# Adding extension libraries to wix when using the JavaFX packager?

Tags: java, javafx, wix, javafx-gradle-plugin, javafx-packager

I'm using the JavaFX packager through the [JavaFX-Gradle-Plugin](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin) and I need to add a couple of [Wix extension libraries to be able to run my app after install](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html).

How do I achieve that?

According to the Wix documentation, by adding `-ext WixUIExtension -ext WixUtilExtension` to the command line, but I don't see how to do it from the JavaFX packager nor [JavaFX-Gradle-Plugin](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into the responsible msi-bundler, I found this fragment:

```
List<String> commandLine = new ArrayList<>();

// (...)
commandLine.add("-ext");
commandLine.add("WixUtilExtension");
if (enableLicenseUI || enableInstalldirUI) {
    commandLine.add("-ext");
    commandLine.add("WixUIExtension.dll");
}

// (...)
```

This means `WixUtilExtension` is always added, and when having the user to choose the installation target directory, the extension `WixUIExtension` gets added too.

To have the user choose the target installation directory, you have to set this inside the jfx-configuration-part:

```
jfx {
// ...
    bundleArguments = [
        'installdirChooser': true
    ]
// ...
}
```

https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin/issues/101

**Disclaimer:** I'm the creator of the javafx-gradle-plugin

Comment: Some additional note: it is not possible to pass additional parameters or extensions, this is a technical limitation how the bundler is implemented